# Unable to login in PHP

Tags: php, authentication

Hei guys, I have been working around to figure out what's wrong here but unable to identify it. I am creating a login page and here the code. Could you please help me to identify it?thnx

```
<?php include 'db.php'; ?>
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

     $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $username);
     $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $password);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE username = '{$username}' ";
    $login_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($login_query)) {
        $db_username = $row['username'];
        $db_password = $row['password'];
        $firstname = $row['firstname'];
        $lastname = $row['lastname'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $db_role = $row['role'];

        if ($username !== '{$db_username}'  &&  $password !== '{$db_password}' ) {
            header("Location: ../index.php");

        }elseif ($username == '{$db_username}'  &&  $password == '{$db_password}') {
            header("Location: ../admin");
        } {
            header("Location: ../index.php");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: First of all: SQL injection. Your code is not safe at all. http://bobby-tables.com - Second point: Your login is not safe at all. You should stop to store passwords as plaintext. Hash the password, ane use password_verify() function from PHP to verify if the inputdata is correct. What you're tying here is really bad practice and shouldn't go online!

Comment: And third - you don't know the difference between single and double qoutes.

Comment: Yea i know it's a bad practice but the problem is even when i put wrong username or password it's still cannot remain in the index page but it redirects to the page where login.php is, however, when i put the correct username and password it remains in the index.php page. I just wonder what is wrong with the code. Thnx

Comment: Assuming this is not all the code in this script, look at your php error log for message like **headers already sent**

Comment: And while testing Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: `$username == '{$db_username}'` ~ PHP variables within single quotes will not be parsed by PHP so instead do something like `$username ==$db_username`

Comment: Also you are missing an ELSE in your if/elseif/**else**

Comment: RamRaider I changed $username == ' {$db_username}' to $username ==$db_username but it's still the same...even i put wrong username and password it still directs to login.php instead to index.php.

Comment: I don't see `login.php`  in the code above. Also, the first `IF` statement should use `OR` rather than `AND` for the logic. Question: are usernames unique in the db?

Comment: why all that coping of variabels: POSTvalues go into $username, $password. the resulting $row['username'] goes into $dbusername etc.

Why not `if($_POST['password'] == $row['password'])` ?

note: $dbusername cannot differ from $username / $_POST['username'] as it is in the WHERE clause of the query.

Answer (score 0):

I did ask whether or not usernames were unique in the db - if they are then there would be no need for a loop and using a loop would mean that on the first iteration into the recordset the logic tests ( that were failing anyway ) would run and the redirection would occur without any further processing.

Perhaps the following might help.

```
<?php
    if( isset( $_POST['login'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['password'] ) ) {

        include 'db.php';

        /*
            Using prepared statements means you don't need to try to sanitize user input data prior 
            to executing the sql query in an attempt to prevent sql injection.
        */
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        /*
            The original query returned many fields which were never used. When using `prepared statements` and binding
            the results you need to specify a binding for all fields returned - hence returning only two fields.
        */
        $query = "SELECT `username`,`password`,`role` FROM `tbl_users` WHERE `username` = ? ";
        $stmt = $connection->prepare( $query );

        if( $stmt ){

            $stmt->bind_param( 's', $username );
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();

            /* Capture db results into variables to use in logic test below */
            $stmt->bind_result( $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbrole );

            $stmt->fetch();
            $stmt->close();
            $connection->close();

            /* possible endpoints for redirection */
            $redirect = 'login.php';

            if( $username == $dbusername && $password == $dbpassword ) {
                /* What values are held in `role` field? assumed "admin" */
                $redirect = $dbrole == 'admin' ? 'admin' : 'index.php';
            }

            exit( header( "Location: ../{$redirect}" ) );

        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I notice that the original code has a `role` field in the recordset but was unused. The fact that the original code only displayed 2 possible redirection locations lead me to maintain 2 endpoints but I think the `role` should also be used to determine who gets access to `admin`

Comment: Also here, please take note of the password_hash() and password_verify() function, since saving passwords in plaintext is not good at all.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `$username !== '{$db_username}'` while you can use `$username !== $db_username` directly? It isn't necessary to use quotes when you are comparing strings without any modification...

Also, if you want to parse variables within quotes, DON'T use single quotes, because them will not be parsed by PHP. Using single quotes you are always comparing `$username` with '{$db_username}'. Instead, use double quotes which will be parsed by PHP.

Here's an example of what i'm saying:

```
<?php
$db_username = 'admin';

$username = $_POST['username']; // asumming it is 'admin'

if($username == '{$db_username}') // will be false because 'admin' != '{$db_username}'

if($username == "{$db_username}") // will be true because 'admin' == 'admin'
if($username == $db_username)     // same as before but cleaner (and a little bit faster, maybe?)
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A login generally need a session to store informations about your status.
So, first thing to do is initialize the sessions, put this code at top of the page, before all:

```
session_start();
```

After this, a few considerations must be done:

- I'll expect that the field `username` is unique: put a unique index on your db on this field to ensure the unicity
- Change your query, putting the password check inside it
- Fetch only one row, without using a `while`: if the username is unique you will get only one row. The password can be checked inside query as said before, so if query dest not return rows, user is not registered or credentials are wrong.
- If you get results, then you can check the role and redirect to the right page.

If you can authenticate the user, set a session like:

```
$_SESSION['user'] = array(
    'is_logged' => $user_id,
    'username' => $username,
    'role' => $role,
    'email' => $email,
);
```

Every time you load a page, check `if(empty($session['user']['is_logged'])) { .... }`. If true, the user is not logged.

Don't save user password as plain text, but hash it! You can use MySQL `PASSWORD()` function.

```
$username !== '{$db_username}'  &&  $password !== '{$db_password}'
```

This code will not work, and probably is the main problem, single quotes are not parsed by PHP, use `$username == $db_username && $password == $db_password` instead (if you do this check inside the query, this code is not neeeded anymore)